# Asynchronous file downloads in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to download multiple files asynchronously in Python(2.6) preferably via Requests Module. Gevent and Twisted will also be acceptable as I'll be learning them in the near future.

My application requires the download of 40+ files in a short period of time, I want to continuously download all the files 4 at a time. And every-time one file download completes another one is started so it stays at 4.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to use any external library or framework for such a simple task, put the list of urls in a queue, start 4 threads and each thread should take an item from queue and download it.

something like this:

```
import sys
import os
import urllib
import threading
from Queue import Queue

class DownloadThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, destfolder):
        super(DownloadThread, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.destfolder = destfolder
        self.daemon = True

    def run(self):
        while True:
            url = self.queue.get()
            try:
                self.download_url(url)
            except Exception,e:
                print "   Error: %s"%e
            self.queue.task_done()

    def download_url(self, url):
        # change it to a different way if you require
        name = url.split('/')[-1]
        dest = os.path.join(self.destfolder, name)
        print "[%s] Downloading %s -> %s"%(self.ident, url, dest)
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, dest)

def download(urls, destfolder, numthreads=4):
    queue = Queue()
    for url in urls:
        queue.put(url)

    for i in range(numthreads):
        t = DownloadThread(queue, destfolder)
        t.start()

    queue.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    download(sys.argv[1:], "/tmp")
```

usage:

```
$ python download.py http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4
[4456497152] Downloading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1 -> /tmp/1
[4457033728] Downloading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2 -> /tmp/2
[4457701376] Downloading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3 -> /tmp/3
[4458258432] Downloading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4 -> /tmp/4
```

Comment: But that's not asynchronous, right? We're blocking thread until file is downloaded.

Comment: @user2963977 downloading in separate thread in asynchronous with main thread, in the example we had nothing to do, so we waited but you can have done something else e.g. showing stats to user or play tic-tac-toe with him until file downloads

Comment: Wait, what? with GIL, the program is not going do anything else right?

Comment: @0xc0de GIL doesn't mean that multi threading doesn't work, GIL only affects computation not blocking calls on IO